# Get the column names for given values in each row

Tags: r, data.table

I need to create a new column in my data table that contains a string of all the column names depending on the values within each row.

In the example below I only want to return the column names where all the values in the row are > 1 but this may change.  The column names will be used as a formula in a regression model.

The reason for this is I want to build a model per group but within each group some of the variables have zero variance.  Some are also categorical/factors but only have 1 level so I can exclude these variables from the model based on the column names.

example data table with the result column being the required output.

```
dt <- data.table(dept = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
             x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
             x2 = c(5,4,3,2,1),
             Result = c("x1", "x1 + x2", "x1 + x2", "x1 + x2", "x2"))
```

Comment: With `apply(dt[,2:3]>1,1,function(x) ifelse(length(colnames(dt)[2:3][x])>1,paste0(colnames(dt)[2:3][x],collapse="+"),colnames(dt)[2:3][x]) )` you get `[1] "x2"    "x1+x2" "x1+x2" "x1+x2" "x1" ` ,  could you confirm your expected result

Comment: the column 'Result' in my data table is the expected result.

Comment: How do you explain the condition `rowObs >1` vs. Result rows 1 and 5

Comment: If you have only two columns, you could do `c(NA, "x1", "x2", "x1 + x2")[1 + (dt[["x1"]] > 1) + 2 * (dt[["x2"]] > 1)]` which will probably the fastest solution one could possibly think of (borrowed from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39880045/3001626))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a nice use case for the `set` function in order to avoid by-row operations. This will look like a lot of code but this should be efficient for a big data set

```
## Create an empty "Res" column
set(dt, j = "Res", value = "")

## Loop though c("x1", "x2") columns and update the "Res" column
for (j in c("x1", "x2")) {
  indx <- which(dt[[j]] > 1)
  set(dt, i = indx, j = "Res", value = paste(dt[["Res"]][indx], j, sep = " + "))
}

## Get rid of leading `+`
set(dt, j = "Res", value = sub(" + ", "", dt[["Res"]], fixed = TRUE))

dt
#    dept x1 x2  Result     Res
# 1:    a  1  5      x1      x2
# 2:    b  2  4 x1 + x2 x1 + x2
# 3:    c  3  3 x1 + x2 x1 + x2
# 4:    d  4  2 x1 + x2 x1 + x2
# 5:    e  5  1      x2      x1
```

Comment: Thank you, my actual data set is quite large and this was a very efficient solution.

Comment: agree that when large data.tables then my answer would get a hit back . +1 for this new approach. I always wondered if there was a replacement for `apply()`'s rowwise appraoch. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
dt[, new_col := paste0(colnames(.SD)[.SD>1], collapse = "+"), 1:nrow(dt), .SDcols = c("x1", "x2")]
#dt
#   dept x1 x2  Result new_col
#1:    a  1  5      x1      x2
#2:    b  2  4 x1 + x2   x1+x2
#3:    c  3  3 x1 + x2   x1+x2
#4:    d  4  2 x1 + x2   x1+x2
#5:    e  5  1      x2      x1
```

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek here you observe that your data was incorrect for the last row.. the answer shows that

Comment: you are right, I did make a mistake in the question. Thanks for the answer, it's good to see different ways of getting the desired results.

Comment: I like the fact your answer is on one line but I want to get to know the 'set' function more because it is very fast.  The system time was `0.02` for your answer and David's answer registered `0` on my actual data set.  I've never had anything show a `0` time so I'm not sure if something has gone wrong.